# How to download pdf with no url

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax

I am building a system which sells pdf's to our customers. We have a 3rd party which creates and manages the pdf's. When a purchase is made, our api calls their api which returns a byte[].

How do I start a download from this?

Example process:

*User clicks Purchase*

Javascript makes ajax call -> /api/PurchaseProduct/product/information

*C# then calls 3rd party api in similar fashion*

*Return is a byte[] - Which is the document*

From here I don't know if the byte[] should be returned to the browser or if something else should happen. If I return the byte[] does javascript then need to turn it into a pdf? Should C# be turning the byte[] into a pdf and then return that?

I am afraid this is very new and im not sure where to start.

Thanks

**Edit**

We use ASP.Net MVC and our site is a single page application.

File size varies depending on what is purchased.

Comment: Does the byte array contain the pdf file itself?

Comment: what server technology; ASP.NET, MVC?

Comment: Without a link to the documentation of both mentioned API's, this question will probably remain unanswered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the method, which is called by AJAX, include the following:

```
Current.Response.ClearHeaders();
Current.Response.ClearContent();
Current.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=file.pdf");
Current.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Current.Response.BinaryWrite(returnedByte);
Current.Response.End();
```

where `returnedByte` is the `byte[]`

Answer (score 3):

There are no way of returning a file to the user via AJAX. The browser has to request the file using a normal, HTTP request.

The best solution would be to save the file to disk after the ajax request, and then return the path to the client so that the file can be opened as usual with e.g. window.open.